# Usb device detection

Tags: c++, c, linux, usb, udev

I'm developing an application on C/C++ that should permit user identification on workstations using a variety of biometric devices.
While I plan on delegating user authentication to PAM I also need to detect whether a device has been either connected or disconnected dynamically.

I've checked on udev but I'm not sure it fits with what I want. Is that possible using that library?

Also is there any tutorial available so I can check any examples on udev's usage?

Comment: I'm not sure if you have seen this: http://www.signal11.us/oss/udev/

Comment: I didn't I'll check the link, thanks!